# what's the difference between did and was doing?

Tags: meaning, progressive-aspect

Here are examples of the sentences.  What is the difference between them?
They seem to be almost the same to me so I don’t exactly understand the difference.

> We worked from 9:00 am to 5:00 pm yesterday.
>   We were working from 9:00 am to 5:00 pm yesterday.
>
> When we came home, she talked with her friends.
>   When we came home, she was talking with her friends.
>
> I slept when the cat came in through the window.
>   I was sleeping when the cat came in through the window.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example I like to use with my students.

> Sarah says, "I **was doing** my homework and my friend called."
>
>
> Rachel says, "I **did** my homework and my friend called."

This means that Rachel finished her homework, but Sarah did not finish her homework. The "was doing" means that something was still going on, that it was interrupted or that it never finished.

For my info, you could see [englishpage.com's article](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

"We worked from 9 am to 5 pm yesterday" implies that work only took place from 9-5, but "we were working from 9:00 to 5:00 yesterday" implies that, in addition to having worked from 9-5, work may have also been taking place before and/or after the period of 9-5.

Answer (score 0):

> We worked from 9 am to 5 pm yesterday.

is best as a simple statement of fact. But you could use:

> We were working from 9:00 to 5:00 yesterday. Around 1:00 the power went out.

if you are describing other things that were going on at that time.

> When we came home, she was talking with her friends.
>   I was sleeping when the cat came in through the window.

are best. Since you are describing activities occurring in the present (based on your narrative) *she was talking* and *the cat came in*, you should keep the same tense in the other phrase.