# "I called you", or "I was calling you"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I was calling you yesterday; you didn’t answer.

or

I called you yesterday but you didn’t answer.

Comment: To make this a good question you should include:  What you think the answer should be, why you think that, and why you think this is a difficult problem.

Comment: Is "I tried calling you yesterday, but I didn't get an answer. " a valid sentence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what's the difference between did and was doing?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29225/whats-the-difference-between-did-and-was-doing)

Answer (score 5):

Both are grammatical, but a native speaker of US english would be far more likely to use the second form:

> I called you yesterday, but you didn’t answer.

Other possible variants:

> - I called you yesterday, but no one answered.
> - I called you yesterday, but I didn't get an answer.

Perhaps because the activity of calling has been completed before the speaker is speaking, `"I called"` is much more common than `"I was calling"` is.

[This Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+was+calling%2CI+called&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20was%20calling%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20called%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20was%20calling%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20called%3B%2Cc0) shows that my empirical impression of frequency has a basis.

Answer (score 3):

I would also add that "I was calling you yesterday" implies at least one attempt, whereas "I called..." suggests only one attempt.

Comment: "I called ..." suggests _at least_ one attempt, but maybe more.
And "I was calling you ..." could be followed up with: "but then I got interrupted and didn't complete."

Answer (score 1):

You would usually say,

I called you yesterday, but you didn't answer.

Was calling would be something like :

I was calling yesterday but realized you were in a meeting. Or I was calling you yesterday when I got a call from my mom.

(a) I called.
(b) I was calling...